# iterating a stock tick data with append on python

Tags: python, loops, append, concatenation, stock

I am trying to combine a series of stock tick data based on the dates.
But it wont work. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import tushare as ts


def get_all_tick(stockID):

    dates=pd.date_range('2016-01-01',periods=5,freq='D')
    append_data=[]

    for i in dates:

        stock_tick=pd.DataFrame(ts.get_tick_data(stockID,date=i))
        stock_tick.sort('volume',inplace=True, ascending=False)
        stock_tick=stock_tick[:10]
        stock_tick.sort('time',inplace=True, ascending=False)

        append_data.append(stock_tick.iterrows())


get_all_tick('300243')
```

Comment: What do you mean it wont work, are you getting errors? Unexpected output? You need to provide more details if you want help

Comment: my bad. It does not show anything after running the code. I assume  i might use the loops function wrong. I just learned the python two weeks ago and tried to use it with financial data.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out myself.

```
def get_all_tick(stockID):
.........
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in get_date:

    stock_tick = ts.get_tick_data(stockID, date=i)
    stock_tick['Date']=i
    stock_tick.sort('volume', inplace=True, ascending=False)
    stock_tick = stock_tick[:10]
    stock_tick.sort('time', inplace=True, ascending=False)
    df = df.append(stock_tick)

    df.to_excel('tick.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

get_all_tick('300243')
```